# Can I generate non clustered index for one or more columns using flask- sqlalchemy declarations alone

Tags: flask

I am using Flask-sqlalchemy with pyodbc on a remote mssql database, I want to implement full text search, I dont have much control over the database other than seeing that Full text search is enabled.Do I need to ask the owner to create a full text catalog and index on the database or can I implement it in the flask application with  db model declaration.